# How to trigger refactoring as part of Quickfix

Tags: java, eclipse, xtext, emf

I need to trigger rename action when i click the Quickfix in the IDE.
For example, I have warning for local duplicate element.In this case i need to offer quickfix to rename the element. So please let me  know how to offer rename quickfix.

I found the below link but it's not useful for my scenario. I want to trigger rename functionality as similar to Rename context menu.

[How to use rename refactoring as part of a quickfix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480917/how-to-use-rename-refactoring-as-part-of-a-quickfix)

Please let me know some suggestion.

Many thanks in advance.